# Getting Error when try to add external font in React Native App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nativescript, custom-font

I am new in react native and facing issue when trying to add external downloaded font in my first app. system giving below errors

1. Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
2. Check the render method of `LandingPage`.

and attaching image of code what I written. please suggest the solution and thanks in advance
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get this error: `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined` is because the component/function/class that you are using is not imported properly.

There is the different between

```
import { MyComponent } from './path-to-component/MyComponent.js'
```

and

```
import MyComponent from './path-to-component/MyComponent.js'
```

if you exported a component from the other file with `export default class MyComponent` then you should import it with this statement `import MyComponent from './path-to-file/MyComponent.js'`

but if you exported a component with this statement `export class MyComponent` then you should import it with this statement `import { MyComponent } from './path-to-file/MyComponent.js'`

My suggestion is to check your exported `class`, `function`, and `component`, and the other file that imports it.